# Grails Spring Events Plugin not found

Tags: events, grails, grails-plugin, grails-3.1

After upgrading grails from 2.2 to 3.1 I can no longer compile the spring-events plugin.

In my 2.2 project I had the plugin set in build-config.groovy

plugins{
compile ':spring-events:1.2'
}

But now there is a build.gradle file and when I add the plugin, it cannot be found.

Has anyone had issues with this?

Comment: Instead use http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/async.html#events

Comment: @mehmood thanks, my code is built around Spring context using ApplicationEvent so I didn't want to change too much code but looks like i'll have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring events` plugin is not compatible with Grails 3.x. You can find a list of supported plugins in the repository over at [Bintray](https://bintray.com/grails/plugins).